# How is resynchronization performed for security keys / MFA devices?

Tags: multi-factor, time, synchronization

When a MFA (time based) device security key drifts out of synchronization there is a procedure to resynchronize it.  But there is no input to the device itself.

Smartphone apps don't have this problem.  I assume this is because the app has access to the accurate clock from the telco provider(s).  Security key devices need to have their own clock or source of time, which can be attacked (receive it over a radio signal such as WWV or CHU in North America), or drift (internal clock).  I am guessing all the devices I have seen use an internal clock, because there many reports of them needing to be resynchronized, often.  But it is not obvious how this is done so quickly, or done in places with no clock sources.  It is also not obvious why an administrative setting is needed to resynchronize the device.

Can someone explain (or provide a good link that explains) how the device gets resynchonized?  I want to understand the degree of risk this might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For time based tokens there are basically two methods.

First of all, as the time In a token cannot be manipulated (either it is a isolated frob with bad clock or it is hosted on a system where you cannot influence the clock).

So what needs to be done is on the authentication server, you keep a estimated time offset (or more complex compensation model) and adjust it on each login.

Basically you compare the input from the current authentication with a few codes before and after the current code. If it matches you know a offset to apply next time.

This correction method can be as complicated as you want, since you don’t want to allow an attacker to influence your estimates or you don’t want to make the window too big as it allows more guessing. (For example keep a history of the latest 3 authentications and offsets and do a linear regression to find not only the offset but also the slope of difference)

If you decide that the time drift is too big (or you have no initial data for prediction) you ask for multiple entries. This will reduce the risk of accepting a repeating code (in a too wide timespan).

For the initial registration you probably want to allow a wider timespan before you reject a token (however be careful if the token has a broken clock and you accept the registration you might risk that a future login fails, which is more annoying than rejecting a device registration)

The exactly same mechanism applies to counter based systems as well (with the additional task to account for missed timer updates and luckily never negative offsets)

Comment: what if a token is *way* off (many minutes, say 20+ minutes when the code change interval is 30 seconds) when first registered in the authentication server?

Comment: At first registration when you do not fear stolen codes you simply search a very wide timeoffset window. You can request two codes in sequence to make that more reliable (because the codes are short so you might have multiple hits). If it’s more than a few days you probably have to say the token is broken.

Comment: Adjusted the answer.